# letterpaper margin to a4paper margin

Tags: margins, geometry, paper-size

I have a document typeset in `letter` paper size. I obtained it with the `fullpage` package, which sets all 4 margins to be 1 inch.

Now I would like to use the `a4paper` option, but keeping exactly the same text width (I spent time to adjust some equations).

What size should I pass to the `geometry` package together with the `a4paper` option? Seems that 1 inch is not the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see that an exact solution depends on how you define 1 Inch in cm or mm. I simply use here the fixed version for

> ```
> 1 Inch = 25.4 mm.
> ```

Be aware of rounding errors for the conversion of Inch to mm ...

Because you gave no mwe (please next time add one!) I can only guess what you are doing.
Please see the following MWE containing the "formula" to get the current `\textwidth` with paper `letter` and the calculation for the needed length of margins for the useage of paper A4 with the same `\textwidth`. Simply move the `%` from one call of `geometry` to the other to get first paper `letter`, second `a4`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe, letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry} % <====================
%\usepackage[showframe, a4paper, margin=22.4mm]{geometry} % <====================
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

Format \texttt{letter} is defined to be: 216mm x 279mm.

1 inch is defined as 25.4mm, 
so your text width here is 216mm-25.4mm-25.4mm = 165.2mm % <=====================

Format \texttt{A4} is defined to be: 210mm x 297mm. 

The difference in paper width is 6 mm (rounded!). 
Therefore to get the same text width you need 
margins with 22.4mm: 210mm-22.4mm-22.4mm = 165.2mm. % <=====================

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

and the resulting letter pdf:

[image: resulting letter page]

The marked text width (with both red arrows pointing on the typing area at the same height) is 165.2 mm for letter paper and for a4 paper after moving the `%` as already mentioned ...

So at last the answer to your question is:

use

```
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=22.4mm]{geometry}
```

to get the same text width, but be aware of changing page numbers in longer documents, because the text height is changed too between the two paper sizes `letter` and `a4` ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So it was only basic computations... By the way I checked the geometry package documentation and it is possible to set the textwidth instead of the margin. Which option would you choose ?

Comment: @JCoulet depends on what you need ... Do you need same margin right and left? Use `margin`. Need only textwidth fixed, margin not fixed: use `textwidth=` ...